# Ways to store a portion of html code on browser cache or fetch it from somewhere

Tags: html, browser, browser-cache

I started making a website, then I realized that I was pasting the top menu all over the html pages from the website. This isn't the best way to do that I thought. So, how do I manage to have the same menu on all the pages I want, without pasting this information all the time.

Is that possible to store "head" tag information too? Because the html code looks a little messy with so many things up there all the time.

Sending a portion of html code to browser cache is possible? I know that browsers sometimes do that with favicon or background images.

Doing that seems quite... Useful, because the user will not load the "same stuff" every time he access the pages. Despite to the fact that if you send something to the cache, you need to clear the browser cache to see the effects if the content has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use php function [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

**Example:**
header.php:

```
<h1>My header</h1>
```

otherpage.php source:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
?>
rest of the page...
```

otherpage.php output:

```
<h1>My header</h1>
rest of the page...
```